# ISNULL is still returning NULL values

Tags: sql

I've this query:

```
SELECT        cod_commessa, (ISNULL(ccomm.costi, 0) + ISNULL(ccomm.imp_costi, 0) - ISNULL(ccomm.rid_costi, 0)) -
                             ((SELECT        ISNULL(costi, 0) AS Expr1
                                 FROM            t_costi_commesse AS tbs
                                 WHERE        (cod_commessa = ccomm.cod_commessa) AND (anno = YEAR(DATEADD(m, - 1, CAST(CAST(ccomm.anno AS varchar) + REPLICATE('0', 
                                                          2 - LEN(CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar))) + CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar) + '01' AS smalldatetime)))) AND (mese = MONTH(DATEADD(m, - 1, 
                                                          CAST(CAST(ccomm.anno AS varchar) + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar))) + CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar) 
                                                          + '01' AS smalldatetime))))) +
                             (SELECT        ISNULL(imp_costi, 0) AS Expr1
                               FROM            t_costi_commesse AS tbs
                               WHERE        (cod_commessa = ccomm.cod_commessa) AND (anno = YEAR(DATEADD(m, - 1, CAST(CAST(ccomm.anno AS varchar) + REPLICATE('0', 
                                                         2 - LEN(CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar))) + CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar) + '01' AS smalldatetime)))) AND (mese = MONTH(DATEADD(m, - 1, 
                                                         CAST(CAST(ccomm.anno AS varchar) + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar))) + CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar) 
                                                         + '01' AS smalldatetime))))) -
                             (SELECT        ISNULL(rid_costi, 0) AS Expr1
                               FROM            t_costi_commesse AS tbs
                               WHERE        (cod_commessa = ccomm.cod_commessa) AND (anno = YEAR(DATEADD(m, - 1, CAST(CAST(ccomm.anno AS varchar) + REPLICATE('0', 
                                                         2 - LEN(CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar))) + CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar) + '01' AS smalldatetime)))) AND (mese = MONTH(DATEADD(m, - 1, 
                                                         CAST(CAST(ccomm.anno AS varchar) + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar))) + CAST(ccomm.mese AS varchar) 
                                                         + '01' AS smalldatetime)))))) AS 'costi'
                                                         FROM            t_costi_commesse AS ccomm INNER JOIN
                         t_commesse AS comm ON ccomm.cod_commessa = comm.codcema
```

This query is returning values correctly, but sometimes I have some values in column 'costi' that still are NULL, even if I apply ISNULL to every value. The weird thing is that sometimes a NULL value is correctly replaced with 0, but sometimes not.

I'm also sure that the original value is NULL (and not maybe a string 'NULL'), because SQL Server Management Studio changes correctly the background color.

So, I can understand if my query is incorrect or if ISNULL in not working properly for an unknown reason. Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)?

Comment: @JimmySawczuk - for two parameters and ignoring weird type rules, they can be though of as equivalent.

Comment: If you want to filter out rows with NULL values, you have to specify it in the WHERE statement, like, for example, `WHERE ccomm.costi IS NOT NULL
AND ccomm.imp_costi IS NOT NULL
AND ccomm.rid_costi IS NOT NULL`
at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `ISNULL`s that you're applying *within* your subqueries to the outside.

This:

```
select 1,(select object_id from sys.objects where 1=0)
```

Produces:

```
1,  NULL
```

Despite the fact that `object_id` isn't nullable, because the subquery returns no rows. You can't fix it in the `select` of the subquery because there are no rows. So this:

```
select 1,(select ISNULL(object_id,0) from sys.objects where 1=0)
```

**doesn't** fix the issue but this:

```
select 1,ISNULL((select object_id from sys.objects where 1=0),0)
```

does.